# Wordpress 別途データベース接続

Tags: aws, wordpress

WordPressに使っているローカルのデータベース以外にRDSで接続したいのですが、どの部分のPHPファイルにPDO構文を書くのが適切でしょうか？

デザインテンプレートのindex.phpに書くのはおかしいですよね？
目的としてはプラグインを使わずに、アクセス数やリファラ、コメントなどを実装したいです。
RDSを使って、高速化できるかどうかも調べたいです。

Comment: 一般的に仮想マシンはディスクIOがボトルネックになりやすいです。動作速度に物理的な制約があるデバイスを複数の仮想マシンで共有する上に、実際に物理的に書き込まれるまでの階層も多いので、ボトルネックになるのは避けられません。RDSもEC2やと同じく仮想マシンを提供している事にはかわりありません。通常提供している仮想マシンに比較して、データベースのようにディスクIOが頻繁に発生する用途に特化して最適化が施されています。RDSを使うことで、通常の仮想マシン上にデータベースを構築した場合よりも高速になるか否かは、場合によるので一概には言えません。

Cloud上の仮想マシンの最適化を試みる場合、仮想マシンに割り当てられる揮発性ストレージの活用が鍵になると思います。揮発性ストレージは仮想ディスクとオンプレミスのストレージと遜色ない速度で動作します。障害時に直近のデータが失われてもかまわないログデータや、通常は読み取り専用にしか使わないデータを揮発性ストレージに配置することで大幅にパフォーマンスが変わってきます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「プラグインを使わずに」ということなので、ごく軽微なデータ取得と推察します。
私ならその場合、functions.php に書くと思います。

[[WordPress] functions.phpを編集、修正、管理しやすくする書き方](http://millkeyweb.com/wp-functions-management/)

> RDSを使って、高速化できるかどうかも調べたいです。

質問の意味が汲み取れないのですが、RDSというのは、`Amazon RDS`のことでしょうか？
RDSだから速くなるという概念がわからないのですが、何と比べてでしょうか？